# Java 8 Instant.range and Instant.with appear inconsistent

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to generate instances of `java.time.Instant` for property-based testing, and using `Temporal.range` works really well for pretty much all the `Temporal` subclasses I've tried 
- except `Instant`, which doesn't seem to provide useful minimum & maximum values.

This simplified example:

```java
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant.EPOCH.with(
      ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS,
      Instant.EPOCH.range(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS).getMaximum()
    );
  }
}
```

Throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Instant exceeds minimum or maximum instant
    at java.time.Instant.create(Instant.java:411)
    at java.time.Instant.with(Instant.java:718)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

A runnable version can be found [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SyE-_8iiH)

A simple counter example is that this equivalent code using `LocalDate` behaves exactly as one would expect from the documentation, correctly handling the variable days of the month:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args){
    for(int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
        LocalDate startOfMonth = LocalDate.of(2019, m, 1);
        LocalDate endOfMonth = startOfMonth.with(
            ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH,
            startOfMonth.range(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH).getMaximum());
        System.out.println(
            startOfMonth.toString() + " -> " + endOfMonth.toString()
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Runnable version [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJmJ0PhoS)

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The range returned by a ChronoField [defers to IsoChronology.range](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#range%28%29), which [says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html#range%28java.time.temporal.ChronoField%29):

> Note that the result only describes the minimum and maximum valid values and it is important not to read too much into them. For example, there could be values within the range that are invalid for the field.

And, indeed, the value returned by `IsoChronology.INSTANCE.range(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS).getMaximum()` is Long.MAX_VALUE.  It is not taking the limitations of Instant into account.

The actual maximum value is defined by [Instant.MAX](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#MAX).

Comment: But does a developer have to expect that `Instant.range` merely delegates to `ChronoField.range()`, especially when the documentation of `Instant.range(TemporalField)` says “*This instant is used to enhance the accuracy of the returned range*”? Your cite, as well as the class documentation of `ValueRange` seem to aim to restrictions that can’t be expressed as [min;max] range, rather than suggesting that an implementation might not even report a clear [min;max] restriction, defeating the entire purpose of `ValueRange`.

Comment: @Holger I agree with you.  I consider it a bug, or a least a needed enhancement, that Instant.range doesn’t do what any reasonable developer would expect, and indeed isn’t really useful at all.  In Java 11, the method’s implementation consists of one line: `return Temporal.super.range(field);`  So, docs notwithstanding, the Instant is not used to enhance the accuracy at all.

Comment: To me this doesn't really address the core issue, as the problem isn't *gaps* inside the reported range, it's that the *maximum* value by `Instant.EPOCH.range(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)` isn't the maximum accepted value. FWIW, none of the other classes I've done this with have had this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: not missing anything, actually a bug

---

Unfortunately, the Java Bug database doesn't have very good visibility, unless you're already there to file a bug.

In an attempt to do so, I found there's already a bug filed for this misbehavior [#8212895](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8212895), which was opened a little more than a year ago (2018-10-18).

At time of writing, it's classed as P4 (P1 is highest priority, P5 is lowest), so it's unlikely to see any love, any time soon.